# Eclipse Installation Error on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I want to install Eclipse, but Eclipse is throwing an exception. 
Here is the log:

```
[2018-01-29 19:40:29] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2018-01-29 19:40:29] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3324)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3252)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3133)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Program Files_Java_Eclipse_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Windows/system32/%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00.
    java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Windows\system32\
```

Comment: Check the last line, it says: "java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Windows\system32\" : Somehow, eclipse cannot create that desired folder. Are you the "Administator" or do you even have rights to run that installation?

Comment: Did you get to try my answer Kevin?

Comment: Thanks, but im the "Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

The latest Eclipse versions

**J2EE**
[Eclipse jee oxygen 2 win32 x86_64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-jee-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=272)

 And **Java**
[Eclipse java oxygen 2 win32 x86_64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-java-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip)

Are just zip files, you should really need to "install" anything, you can just make a folder say on your C drive, call it "Apps" unzip Eclipse in there, run eclipse.exe and make sure you select a workspace are that wouldnt require admin rights